# asp.net html 2 pdf and overlay pdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

i want to generate a PDF file with tables, etc in it. so what i did is using a PDF converter (EVO PDF). that works great, except that the PDF has a white background-color.

What I wanted to do is to overlay a PDF document (because our company paperwork) and put the HTML above it. But because the HTML has a white background, I can't get it work.

I'm now using  EVOPDF to generate the HTML and Syncfusion to overlay the company paperwork..

there must be an easier way

Answer (score 1):

Convert the company stationary into a flat image, and then set that as the background to the page in CSS.  As long as care is taken to measure and set sizing right, that should work for you.

Comment: the pdf can have multiple pages, how about that? does the background still work?

Comment: Again, it can be done by specifying the sizing of the page etc, and inserting multiple background images of required.